# Skip mounted network folder when host is offline

Tags: networking, mount, nautilus

On my desktop Ubuntu 15.10 (**A**) I have mounted some folders on another Ubuntu box (**B**) on my LAN.

I used this guide:

[How to Create a Network Share Via Samba Via CLI (Command-line interface/Linux Terminal) - Uncomplicated, Simple and Brief Way!](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21)

From time to time I turn off the Ubuntu **B** machine and as a result I obviously  cannot see these folders on my desktop machine **A**.

The problem is that Nautilus and my terminal becomes extremely slow when listing content in my user directory (~) since each time it tries to scan for these network directories.

Is there anyway to remove this *hanging* effect and make Ubuntu handle more gracefully when mounted network folders appear/disappear?

Below my **/etc/fstab** file:

```
//living-room.local/living-room  /home/user/living-room-share  cifs uid=user,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include details of how you have mounted them (e.g.  the appropriate section of your fstab file)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an entirely perfect solution, but You could make an easily available script (desktop shortcut?) that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo umount -l /home/user/living-room-share
```

If that does not work, try including the `-f` argument as well.

**Edit:**

An alternative approach could be to avoid mounting your share through fstab altogether, and instead mount the share using Nautilus directly:

1. Open Nautilus and navigate to the share by pressing `CRTL+L` and entering `smb://living-room.local/living-room`
2. From the application menu, select `Bookmarks` > `Bookmark this Location`

This may make Nautilus less unresponsive when the server goes offline after having mounted the share in the first place.